# Use a bash array as a place-in argument list (with Midnight Commander)

Tags: bash, xargs, arguments, mc

I'm having a little bit of trouble figuring out how I can use a bash array for an argument list. so far, the below code **does not work**.

The `%s` below is Midnight Commander specific.

```
F=(%s); for i in "${F[@]}"; \
             do G+=(--floppy_drive_$((n++))="\"$i\""); \
        done; fs-uae ${G[*]}
```

The problem is with this part:

```
fs-uae ${G[*]}
```

However, when I echo the last statement and use xargs, it works fine:

```
Open=FMAX=2; bash -c 'F=(%s); \
       for i in "${F[@]}"; \
          do G+=(--floppy_drive_$((n++))="\"$i\""); \
       done; echo ${G[*]}' | xargs -n $((FMAX*2)) fs-uae
```

Also it seems like I have to use `bash -c` because MC complains about syntax errors otherwise.

I also use this with MESS, since mess emulator needs arguments like `-cart1`, `-cart2`, `-flop1`, etc....

So the above code **works**. I can select two files with the Insert key in Midnight Commander, and just hit enter, and fs-uae will start up with the floppies I've selected. I'm just wondering if there's a better way to do this without xargs?

I've heard people say xargs is "unsafe". How worrisome is this technically?